# Generic Type Parameters With Type Builder

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, c#-3.0, typebuilder

basically I have this class

```
public class MyBase<TEntity> where TEntity : class
{
  //Some retrieval stuff
}
```

and I need to do this

```
public class MyEntity : MyBase<MyModel>
{
  //More Stuff
}
```

but using TypeBuilder

```
public TypeBuilder CreateTypeBuilder(Type GenericTypeParameter)
{
  Type MyGenericTypedBase = ????;
  TypeBuilder type = module.DefineType("MyClassName", TypeAttributes.Public, MyGenericTypedBase);
  ...
  return type;
}
```

#### Thanks in advance

excuse me, the question is how to get the type who should inherit if the generic type parameter is generated with type builder

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, wouldn;t it just be `Type MyGenericTypedBase = typeof(MyBase<MyModel>)`?;

Comment: excuse me, the question is how to get the type who should inherit if the generic type parameter is generated with type builder and would not be possible to use typeof(MyBase<MyModel>)

Answer (score 0):

I just found the answer should be

```
Type MyGenericTypedBase = typeof(MyBase<>);
MyGenericTypedBase = MyGenericTypedBase.MakeGenericType(GenericTypeParameter);
```

thank you all for your answers